# How to populate List View from different activity without starting that activity

Tags: java, android

I want to add list of items to my cart and when user taps the cart option all those items selected from different activities of the app loads to the cart. Intents start a new activity and I don't want to start the cart activity every time user adds any item. I've used shared preferences but it is updating the same list item again and again or crash the app. I am new to android, any help will be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

```
public class NewClass extends Activity {

private ListView mCompleteListView;
private List<String> mItems;
private CompleteListAdapter mListAdapter;
private String myData;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_class);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myData = sharedPreferences.getString("SharedData", "none");

    initViews();
    addItemsToList();
    mItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    mListAdapter = new CompleteListAdapter(this, mItems);
    mCompleteListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
}

private void initViews() {
    mCompleteListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.completeList);

}

private void addItemsToList() {
    mItems.add(myData );
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

I just want to populate list items of cart from several other activities without starting that activity.

Comment: There are many ways to do. Use singletone class with making getter setter method for arraylist or you can take static array list as in _Constant_ class and use it in whole application. You can also use database.

Answer (score -1):

this isn't the best way of doing that, read about viewmodel, 
dialogfragment and room.

long story short you want to create a database that holds the data from the cart. (room) and than you would be able to get that any where in the app.
or
you can hold the data as a var in a viewmodel, and communicate with a dialogfragment (the cart) by getting the viewmodel of the activity.

all the best :)